# Ajax Request Only works locally

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, server, cross-domain

I have this ajax request but it only works locally (no, i am not using local server like wampserver), Am i missing something?

```
$.ajax({
                     url: "http://domain/folder/something.php",
                     dataType: "json",
                     type: "POST",
                      data: {
                                q: enviar
                            },
                    success: function( data ) 
                    {
                        //Some code


                    },//fin success
                 });//Fin ajax
```

also i get this error when the page is in the server: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://pageserver.com' is therefore not allowed access."

so if someone can explain me whats going on, i will be so thankful

Comment: Please google that error. This same issue comes up numerous times a day here and it is not hard to research

Answer (score 0):

What this means is the file you are trying to access does not have permissions set up for your application to talk to it.